# cURL crashing in release mode, not in debug

Tags: c, curl, release

I have used cURL in my app. It works fine (no errors) in debug mode. However, if i switch code to Release build, app start crashing. I am using VC 2013

My code:

```
data_downloads.curl = curl_easy_init();

data_downloads.curlData = (CURL_DOWNLOADED_DATA *)malloc(sizeof(CURL_DOWNLOADED_DATA));
data_downloads.curlData->data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
data_downloads.curlData->data[0] = '\0';

curl_easy_setopt(data_downloads.curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &my_curl_writeCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(data_downloads.curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, data_downloads->curlData);
curl_easy_setopt(data_downloads.curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //tell curl to output its progress

curl_easy_setopt(data_downloads.curl, CURLOPT_URL, USER_INFO_URL);
curl_easy_setopt(data_downloads.curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");


curl_easy_perform(data_downloads.curl); //-- it crashes here
```

Comment: I'm voting to close because your code [doesn't meet the requirements for an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's possible that the problem might be elsewhere; you might be misdiagnosing, and in doing so, wasting all of our time.

Comment: Im encountering the same issue, did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur No.. The problem persist :( And it is really annoying

Comment: @MartinPerry Ive read a few things here about how debug adds some buffering, but I cannot determine what I am doing wrong: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-11/0054.html

Comment: @MartinPerry try to comment out the curl_easy_setopt(data_downloads.curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); and see if it works in release mode, not debug

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in debug mode, VC adds some space to the stack at every of your functions. Would a function briefly be out of bounds and overwrite a few bytes of the stack, then this will not be noticed...until you compile for release.

You should further check that all libraries for the release mode are the proper ones. VC knows many library types for many models (for DLLs, multi-threaded/not, ...). Check them against the libraries for your debugging mode.

These are the issues I came across. There may be other issues.